# Find cards with today date when user receive mails in RoR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Every day I need to send letters to users with today's tasks.

For do this I need  to find all users who are allowed to send letters, and among these users to find all cards that have a deadline today. The result is three array elements with a nil value. How is this better done and right?

```rb
    @users = User.all {|a| a.receive_emails true} 

    @user_cards = []
    @users.each_with_index do |user, index| 
      @user_cards[index] = user.cards.where(start_date: Date.today).find_each do |card|
       @user_cards[index] = card
      end
    end
```

My user model:

```rb
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # also has t.date "start_date"
end
```

My card model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
   # also has t.boolean "receive_emails", default: false
end
```

Comment: Looks like you’ve got an answer whether you want to then iterate through Cards (mine) or Users (@christian bruckmayer). Hope these work out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `@cards_to_send = Card.joins(:users).where("users.receive_emails = true").where(start_date: Date.today)`

Have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables for the docs on how to query on a joined table.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom for the answer. Yea! The conditions on the Connection Table are exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a SQL join like this

```rb
User.joins(:cards).where(receive_emails: true, cards: { start_date: Date.today })
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Queries is exactly what I forgot